# Bad request returned when using the DELETE curl method with Guzzle and sendgrid

Tags: symfony, curl, sendgrid, guzzle

I'm trying to use the [sendgrid v3 API to purge bounces](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/bounces.html#Delete-bounces-DELETE), it works fine when using CURL in CLI, here is the command:

```
curl -v -X DELETE -d '{"delete_all": true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer SG.mykey" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces"
```

But when trying to launch it with Symfony2 / Guzzle, I am getting a bad request error, however the request seems OK, here is the output of `(string) $request`:

```
"""
DELETE /v3/suppression/bounces HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: api.sendgrid.com\r\n
Authorization: Bearer SG.mykey\r\n
User-Agent: Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17\r\n
Accept: application/json\r\n
Content-Length: 20\r\n
\r\n
{"delete_all": true}
"""
```

And the exception:

```
[Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException]   
Client error response                                  
[status code] 400                                      
[reason phrase] BAD REQUEST                            
[url] https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces
```

When using the GET method, it works correctly and it returns me all the bounces.

Here is the guzzle code:

```
$request = $this->httpClient->delete('/v3/suppression/bounces', null, '{"delete_all": true}');
$response = $request->send();
```

The http client is a service initialized with the https://api.sendgrid.com base URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem I think is that you are sending 3 params to delete when it only has two, instead what you need to do is pass the body in options array.

```
$response = $this->httpClient->delete(
        '/v3/suppression/bounces',
        [
            'body' => json_encode(['delete_all', true]),
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),
            'content-type'  => 'application/json'
        ]
    );
```

[Guzzle options docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html)

Comment: I am accepting the answer you have specified the content-type header. But this is for Guzzle6, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed you were on Guzzle/3.9.3, I just looked at what we did to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself. The problem was pretty obvious: The content-type header was not set, the "accept" one was. I didn't care about this header because you don't have to pass it when using the GET method for this API. So now when debugging my request object I have:

```
"""
DELETE /v3/suppression/bounces HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: api.sendgrid.com\r\n
Authorization: Bearer SG.mykey\r\n
Content-Type: application/json\r\n
Content-Length: 20\r\n
User-Agent: Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17\r\n
Accept: application/json\r\n
\r\n
{"delete_all": true}
"""
```